# How to give condition in button Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

How to give conditions in the action of a button /  inkwell or etc?

example

```
InkWell(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(50.0)),
          if => onTap: () {
            capturephoto
            });
          },
          else => onLongPress: () {
            recordvideo
            });
          },
          child: Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
            child: Image.asset(
              'assets/images/ic_switch_camera_3.png',
              color: Colors.grey[200],
              width: 42.0,
              height: 42.0,
            ),
          ),
        ),
```

when i tap it could be photo and if i press it could be record

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need condition there just give both value like this.

```
InkWell(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(50.0)),
      onTap: () {
       // capturephoto
      },
      onLongPress: () {
        //recordvideo
      },
      child: Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
        child: Image.asset(
          'assets/images/ic_switch_camera_3.png',
          color: Colors.grey[200],
          width: 42.0,
          height: 42.0,
        ),
      ),
    ),
```